# How to pass variables in function from a variable

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a problem with creating a query through a function (all others variables works correctly) I have a function that doesn't print variables correctly (exactly $NomiFarmacie and $day)

```
//The problem is present in this function
function Cicla($Periodo, $FarmacieRiordinate, $Query) {
    global $tabella_calendario, $count; //them works

    foreach ($Periodo as $giorno)   {
        $day = $giorno->format("Y-m-d");
        $NomiFarmacie = addslashes($FarmacieRiordinate[$count % count($FarmacieRiordinate)]);

        echo $NomiFarmacie; echo $day; //Both are correct
        print_r($Query); //Queries are not completed correctly. OUTPUT Below
        $count++;
    }
}

$FarmacieRiordinate = $_POST['elementi'];
$DataIniziale = $_POST['data1'];
$DataFinale = $_POST['data2'];
$Query = ("UPDATE $tabella_calendario SET Farmacia='$NomiFarmacie' WHERE Data='$day'");

Cicla(CalcolaPeriodo($DataIniziale, $DataFinale), $FarmacieRiordinate, $Query);
```

**A PORTION OF OUTPUT print_r($Query)**

```
UPDATE calendario SET Farmacia='Array' WHERE Data='1546297200'
UPDATE calendario SET Farmacia='Array' WHERE Data='1546297200'
UPDATE calendario SET Farmacia='Array' WHERE Data='1546297200'
UPDATE calendario SET Farmacia='Array' WHERE Data='1546297200'
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: yes i know, but i have an other problem... (this is an internal and personal calendar!). if I need it I'll fix it

Comment: `$NomiFarmaci` is clearly an array and not a string

Comment: **Farmacia='Array'** that's mean your variable is an array make a print_r or a var_dump on it to seen what is this real value

Comment: @Inazo I know that Faramacia='Array': it corresponds to $NomiFarmacie whose echo works correctly in the foreach. but also the date is wrong while the echo $day is correct

Comment: @JohnConde How can I fill out the queries correctly? Also Data = '1546297200' isn't correct! But i can print $day and $NomiFarmacie correctly in the foreach

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `$Query` already be combined as string BEFORE passed into your function.
You can use `vsprintf` in this case.

```
function Cicla($Periodo, $FarmacieRiordinate, $Query) {
    global $tabella_calendario, $count; //them works

    foreach ($Periodo as $giorno)   {
        $day = $giorno->format("Y-m-d");
        $NomiFarmacie = addslashes($FarmacieRiordinate[$count % count($FarmacieRiordinate)]);

        echo $NomiFarmacie; echo $day; //Both are correct
        $realQuery = vsprintf($Query, array($NomiFarmacie, $day));
        print_r($realQuery); //Queries are not completed correctly. OUTPUT Below
        $count++;
    }
}

$FarmacieRiordinate = $_POST['elementi'];
$DataIniziale = $_POST['data1'];
$DataFinale = $_POST['data2'];
$Query = ("UPDATE $tabella_calendario SET Farmacia='%s' WHERE Data='%s'");

Cicla(CalcolaPeriodo($DataIniziale, $DataFinale), $FarmacieRiordinate, $Query);
```

You can read more about vsprintf here:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php

.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the query before inserting it in the function?

Comment: How do you want to adjust?

Comment: Without using vsprintf in function.I mean before passing it to the function. For example i have different $Query that I have to introduce in the function (some submit) and so in that way i can't use that function everytime without set other variable for check (example $x=1 that will change the $realquery based on need)

Comment: Just dont use it as a parameter of function. Write it in function after command `$NomiFarmacie=...`

Comment: I have various submit and in each of them there is a query. what I mean is if it is possible to pass the query as it is without being re-transformed

Comment: All query are the same as: `UPDATE $tabella_calendario SET Farmacia=something WHERE Data=some-other-thing` or they are difference with each other?

Comment: There are differeces...! For example `"UPDATE $tabella_calendario SET AperturaMATT='$AperturaMATT', ChiusuraMATT='$ChiusuraMATT' WHERE Data='$day'"`

Comment: In this case, I think you should write a separate function to build query. Simple example is:
`function buildUpdateQuery($table, $arrData, $condition) {
    $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET ";
    foreach ($arrData as $column => $value) {
        $query .= "`{$column}='{$value}', ";
   }
   return rtrim($query) . " WHERE {$condition}";
}

Comment: In that way i have the same problem with $day and $NomiFarmacie because i can't pass them through function arguments (them are processed in the function)